# How do I left align an icon and center align text in a 'topbar'

Tags: css

Similar to http://m.huffpost.com/us topbar

Edit: I am trying to create a "responsive menu"
ICON (left aligned) and some TEXT that's centered in a bar at the top

My attempt obviously doesnt work:

```
    <div style="float:left" ><a href="#" id="trigger" class="menu-trigger"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> </a></div>
    <center>Centered Text</center>
```

my menu-trigger class is :

```
   .menu-trigger {
      position: relative;
      padding-left: 60px;
      font-size: 1.5em;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: *Similar to http://m.huffpost.com/us topbar*, *My attempt obviously doesnt work:*, *my menu-trigger class is*, What are you trying to acheive? Could you elaborate please?

Comment: HI, I have updated my question with more detail!
I believe the menu-trigger class can be ignored!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple soutions to the problem. Here's one with the most simple markup:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <a>Menu</a>
    <h1>HELLO</h1>
</div>
```

The `div` is actually not needed necessarily. Here it is used to make a full background color.

**CSS**

```
h1 {
    margin: 0 0 0 80px;        
    text-align: center;
}

a {
    float: right;
    width: 80px;
}
```

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/pcm21qr0/)

[It also works with a menu on the left](http://jsfiddle.net/bwu4831x/)

Comment: @HashemQolami Thanks. And yeah you're right. I took it from the Huffpost example. I added another demo with the new orientation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. Here you have a top bar center aligned and 2 icon links left aligned (50% width as in original link that you posted):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="menu top"><a href="#">Link</a></div>
<div class="menu icon"><img src="" /><a href="#">Link</a></div>
<div class="menu icon"><img src="" /><a href="#">Link</a></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.menu {
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid #333;
    background-color:#ddd;
    padding:10px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-right:-4px;
}

.menu>a {
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.top {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.icon {
    width:50%;
}

.icon>a {
    padding-left:10px;
}

.icon>img {
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid red;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
}
```

Here's the [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/c3g2r77x/1/). Hope it helps.